# UITableView's tableHeaderView height property is changed to strange values during load and rotation

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, frame, autorotate

I have a custom UIView which I set to the tableHeaderView property of a UITableView during loadView:

```
headerView = [[MYViewClass alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 120)];
[headerView sizeToFit];

self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;
```

The view draws incorrectly, with part of the view clipped and white space above the table.  When rotating the device the view almost disappears. On rotating back the view is now bigger that the space for the header and obscures some of the cells in the table.

To troubleshoot I have overrode the setFrame method in my custom view class:

```
- (void) setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    [super setFrame:frame];
    NSLog(@"%@ - %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), NSStringFromCGRect(frame));
}
```

I also put a break point on the NSLog statement so I could see what called the setFrame and I get some odd results that I can't explain and hope someone can shed some light on what is happening and why.

**During loadView**

```
1. initWithFrame calls: setFrame: - {{0, 0}, {320, 120}}
2. sizeToFit calls: setFrame: - {{0, 0}, {320, 109}}
3. setTableHeaderView calls:  setFrame: - {{0, 0}, {320, 109}}
4. _adjustTableHeaderAndFooterViews calls: setFrame: - {{0, 0}, {320, 109}}
5. _resizeWithOldSuperviewSize calls: setFrame: - {{0, 0}, {320, 65}}
6. _adjustTableHeaderAndFooterViews calls: setFrame: - {{0, 0}, {320, 65}}
7. _adjustTableHeaderAndFooterViews calls: setFrame: - {{0, 0}, {320, 65}}
```

**Rotating the device left**

```
1. _resizeWithOldSuperviewSize calls: setFrame: - {{0, 0}, {480, 0}}
2. _adjustTableHeaderAndFooterViews calls: setFrame: - {{0, 0}, {480, 0}}
3. _resizeWithOldSuperviewSize calls: setFrame: - {{0, 0}, {480, 12}}
4. _adjustTableHeaderAndFooterViews calls: setFrame: - {{0, 0}, {480, 12}}
```

**Rotating the device right**

```
1. _resizeWithOldSuperviewSize calls: setFrame: - {{0, 0}, {320, 172}}
2. _adjustTableHeaderAndFooterViews calls: setFrame: - {{0, 0}, {320, 172}}
3. _resizeWithOldSuperviewSize calls: setFrame: - {{0, 0}, {320, 160}}
4. _adjustTableHeaderAndFooterViews calls: setFrame: - {{0, 0}, {320, 160}}
```

Which explains why my view looks truncated initially, then almost disappears and finally ends up overlapping the cells.  It appears that `_resizeWithOldSuperviewSize` is the culprit and what I don't understand is why it is being called and where it is getting these odd values from.

I have a really rubbish work around by calling `[self.tableView.tableHeaderView sizeToFit]` in `viewDidAppear:` and `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` which puts the frame back to the correct size but the redrawing is awful as both happen after the view is visible or after the rotation animation.  Trying to set this anytime before the view is visible causes `_resizeWithOldSuperViewSize` to set the frame back to these odd sizes.

Answer (score 6):

You need to get the intrinsic size and autoresizingMask right. Once you do that, UITableView will stop screwing with your tableHeaderView.

For example, if you want your header to have a fixed height which depends on its contents, but you want your header to use the entire table width, this is what you would do:

1.Create your view with the following Autoresizing mask configuration (so the table won't try to increase the header view height):

[image]

2. Add your subviews using AutoLayout so the top/bottom anchors match your view (this is so your subviews define the height of your header view)

3. Add your header view like so:

```
let headerView : CustomView? = CustomView.fromNib()
headerView?.sizeToFit()

tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
```

Comment: Wau so stupid bug... And I was already fixing it by viewWillTransitionToSize hacking...  Just turning off autosizing for height is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

It will help you to [read up](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) on Apple's view resizing scheme through the `autoresizingMask` property of `UIView`. Possible values are:

```
enum {
    UIViewAutoresizingNone                 = 0,
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin   = 1 << 0,
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth        = 1 << 1,
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin  = 1 << 2,
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin    = 1 << 3,
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight       = 1 << 4,
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin = 1 << 5
};
typedef NSUInteger UIViewAutoresizing;
```

I have no doubt that after some experimentation you will find the right resizing mask combination to solve your problem.

Also, please note that `sizeToFit`, according to the same documentation source "resizes and moves the receiver view so it just encloses its subviews." It seems inappropriate to call that just after creating the view and before putting it into the table header.

Comment: Hi Mundi, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  I'm already familiar with autoresizing masks and setting my headerView's autoresizing mask to None did fix this.  I am still confused as to why the autoresizing mask I had (flexibleRightMargin and flexibleBottomMargin) caused this behaviour.  Why would the table want to try and resize the frame height straight after setting the headerView?  Also why when setting the autoresizing mask to none did the header correctly display after rotation (its frame had been altered to fit the width of the table).  Any ideas?

Comment: Actually, scrub that.  Setting it to None appeared to fix it, but it doesn't.  It stops these extra calls to_resizeWithOldSuperViewSize and the width of the view is correctly specified, but the height is no longer resized.  I need to do some further testing.

Answer (score 1):

Got totally the same problem when I wanted to have table header view with SearchBar and some custom UI at the bottom. The funny thing that if you keep only SearchBar it works just perfect.

So I decided to apply a really dirty hack, reseting Frame's Height in the overridden Frame setter of your custom UIView (there you're logging frame size) to something you need (in your case it's 120).

```
- (void) setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    frame.Height = 120;
    [super setFrame:frame];
}
```

After that there is no weird header view and table overlapping on rotation. Hope it helps.

P.S. BTW I use Auto Layout inside my custom UIView.

Comment: Damn, I nearly lost my remaining hair on this. I don't usually write "thank you" comments, but this is very deserved.

Answer (score -3):

Create a new xib file and then customize your preferred size in the xib file. Say the xib is called customHeader (.xib) Declare:

```
  IBOutlet UIView *customView;
```

Assign customView to that view in your xib.

```
  -(UIView *)viewOfCategory;
```

In .m:

```
   -(UIView *)viewOfCategory {

if (!customView) {

        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"customHeader" owner:self options:nil];
}

return customView;
   }
```

Then call this UITableView method:

```
  -(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:        (NSInteger)section {

return [self customView];

}
```

THEN FINALLY AND MOST IMPORTANT THAT WILL ANSWER YOUR QUESTION! Implement this other UITableView method:

```
   -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

// You can just return default size of your xib: return [[self viewOfCategory]          bounds].size.height;


       // Or you can return custom size using  CGRect or whatever. 
     }
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't think this is it.  I am not setting the view for the section header but the header for the entire table.